# Python framework for block simulations with graphical user interface (like OpenModelica, LabView)?

Tags: open-source, python

Is there a **python** based open source alternative to OpenModelica/LabView/[Scilab Xcos](https://www.scilab.org/download/scilab-2023.1.0), that allows to
define **block diagrams** in a **graphical user interface**, based on predefined
building blocks? And then use that block diagram as a model definition.

I would like to model table calculations and allow users to define the calculation workflow with drag & drop block diagrams.

So far I could only find tools **without GUI**:

https://pypi.org/project/bdsim/

https://github.com/masfaraud/BMSpy

https://simupy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html

PyLab_Works (discontinued)

**Related questions:**

[JavaScript framework for block simulations with graphical user interface (like OpenModelica, LabView)?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/87189/javascript-framework-for-block-simulations-with-graphical-user-interface-like-o)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76359121/how-to-show-results-of-a-static-model-in-modeling-view-with-openmodelica

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76383253/how-to-show-result-of-static-model-plain-number-in-xcos

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76359322/is-there-a-data-frame-data-type-in-openmodelica

Answer (score 2):

Here are some python tools I could find:

## Active

### Orange3

Was able to install and start it.

```
pip install orange3
orange-canvas
```

However, did not manage to write custom component. Documentation seems to be outdated.

https://orangedatamining.com/

https://orangedatamining.com/widget-catalog/

https://github.com/biolab/orange3

https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/6459

### nodeedge

not compatible with python 3.11.1 yet

https://github.com/nodedge/nodedge

https://github.com/nodedge/nodedge/issues/198

### Ryven

Looking for new maintainer; not compatible to python 3.11.1 yet

https://github.com/leon-thomm/Ryven

https://github.com/leon-thomm/Ryven/issues/101

https://github.com/leon-thomm/Ryven/issues/138

## Last change older than one year

### AnimationFreeCad

https://github.com/QuentinTournier40/AnimationFreeCAD

## Outdated/abandoned projects

### PyFlow

https://github.com/wonderworks-software/PyFlow

https://github.com/wonderworks-software/PyFlow/issues/112

https://github.com/wonderworks-software/PyFlow/issues/115