# JavaScript framework for block simulations with graphical user interface (like OpenModelica, LabView)?

Tags: javascript, simulation, flowchart

Is there a **JavaScript** based open source alternative to OpenModelica/LabView/[Scilab Xcos](https://www.scilab.org/download/scilab-2023.1.0), that allows to
define **block diagrams** in a **graphical user interface**, based on predefined
building blocks? And then use that block diagram as a model definition.

I would like to model table calculations and allow users to define the calculation workflow with drag & drop block diagrams.

Related questions:

[Python framework for block simulations with graphical user interface (like OpenModelica, LabView)?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/87166/python-framework-for-block-simulations-with-graphical-user-interface-like-openm/87169#87169)

Answer (score 0):

Some JavaScript libraries about Flow Charts:

https://github.com/bcakmakoglu/vue-flow

https://jeffreyrn.github.io/vue-simple-flowchart/

https://reactflow.dev/docs/examples/interaction/drag-and-drop/

https://www.mermaidflow.app/

https://jerosoler.github.io/Drawflow/

https://gojs.net/latest/samples/blockEditor.html

https://github.com/alyssaxuu/flowy#example

https://www.jointjs.com/demos/flowchart

https://github.com/sdrdis/jquery.flowchart

http://diagramo.com/

Lists:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33385312/javascript-library-to-develop-a-flowchart-simulator-in-html

https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/epw7wp/recommendations_for_a_drag_and_drop_flow_chart/

https://www.jqueryscript.net/blog/best-flowchart.html

https://modeling-languages.com/javascript-drawing-libraries-diagrams/

https://www.getapp.com/project-management-planning-software/flowchart/f/drag-drop-interface/